# No confirmations, waited for months!

Tags: mtgox, confirmations, lost-transactions

I sent a payment of 0.9995 bitcoins back in April to my MtGox account. However I just checked and it has 0 confirmations. Additionally it doesn't show in my wallet or my MtGox account. Is it lost? Can I get it back?

Comment: What is the wallet address?

Comment: Or the transaction ID would also be helpful.

Comment: Was the output perhaps spent in another conflicting transaction?

Comment: those questions are very important to answer. but it is possible(but I only saw this happen twice) to get back if there was an error in your client making the transaction invalid... Sadly it would be considered a double spend... but it would make the first problematic transfer be rejected, and you could spend your money.

Comment: What wallet service are you using?

Answer (score 4):

If your transaction from April still has no confirmation, it would be feasible to create another transaction that spends the same input to yourself. You could hope that your new transaction would be verified first, which would invalidate the other transaction and salvage your coins.

Answer (score 1):

Run this option when starting bitcoin-qt:

```
-salvagewallet
```

I've had this exact same issue several times with other coins and it works like magic.